# NoMethodError in Products#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am totally new to programming and I am having trouble. About 10 days ago I started the UT-Rails course on ureddit.com hosted by Richard Schneeman. So far it has been going very well, but I am on week 5 and having trouble. You'll have to excuse me if I don't use the right terminology, as it has been a lot to take in.

https://github.com/zkay/move_logic_to_controllers is the tutorial I am following at the moment.

I am up to step 2. I have replaced the text in `app/views/products/new.html.erb` with the following:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, when I try to add a new product per the tutorial, the rejection I get back is:

```
NoMethodError in Products#create

Showing C:/Sites/move_logic_to_controllers/app/views/products/create.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <h2>Product Created Successfully<h2>
2: 
3: <%= @product.name %> added to the website, it costs: $<%= @product.price %>
Rails.root: C:/Sites/move_logic_to_controllers
```

If I remove the `.name` and `.price` calls the page works, but it doesn't display any of the data I submitted.

In `app/controllers/product_controller.rb` I have the following:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.includes(:user).all
  end
def new
  @product = Product.new
end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.save
      format.html { render :action => "create" }
      format.json { render :json => @product }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json { render :json => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Sorry if this is long winded. I appreciate any help.

Comment: where is your `create` action in your controller?

Comment: /facepalm. I just added def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])
  end, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Wait, I just saved all the files I had open and it worked? But I changed <%= @products.name %> in the create view back to product and it worked. Can someone explain why that works?

Comment: good..its because you were creating an object with some other name and accessing it with some other name..if that solved your problem than mark the answer as selected...

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. So in the view, I was referencing @products, but in the controller, I was referencing @product?

Comment: no i guess you havent added the code in first place, you later added the code as you have said it 2nd comment, and then later changing the `@product` to `@products` helped you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `<%= @products.name %>`

Comment: in what view are you calling this..??

Comment: /app/views/products/create.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

> /app/views/products/create.html.erb

You don't want to use create.html.erb.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.includes(:user).all
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])

    if @product.save
      redirect_to products_path, notice: "You added product"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Something wrong!"
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

If you use Rails 4 use:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)

  if @product.save
    redirect_to products_path, notice: "You added product"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Something wrong!"
    render :new
  end
end

private

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price)
end
```